# How i can take the value of a number type on kibana scripted field

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elasticsearch-painless

I want to convert all the values of my Pie, they are in second and i want to convert them in min.

The problem is I can't take the value of my index "log_data_numerical" (it's a number type)
but i can take the value of another type example: "log_data_name" (keyword type).

I wrote that:

```
def test = doc['log_data_name'].value; 
return 2;
```

and when i try to take numerical like that

```
def test = doc['log_data_numerical'].value;
return 2;
```

I got

> Script is invalid. View script preview for details

so please if someone has an idea it will help me a lot!

Here is some pictures:

- My Pie [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xBdas.png)
- Two indexes with their values [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7GXWv.png)
- The scripted field with the error [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FaKVc.png)

Comment: remove the `.value` and check.

Comment: It's work thx lot !

Comment: posted same as answer as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove `.value` for numerical field as shown below.

```
def test = doc['log_data_numerical'];
return 2;
```